# Architecting Rails Model instance methods to bring in specific model attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

This should be fairly easy, but for the sake of understanding best practices I want to check.

I have a `TextMessage` model. Let's say there are 10 different `TextMessage`s in my database.

Each one has a `from_number` and a `message` attribute. I want to send a `TextMessage.message` from `TextMessage.from_number` to `to_number`.

So, it seems like this logic should live on my model:

```
class TextMessage < ActiveRecord::Base

  def test(to_number)
    twilio_api = TwilioProviders::TextProvider.new
    twilio_api.send_text(from_number, to_number, message)
  end

end
```

How do I make sure `from_number` is the current models `from_number` whenever I run:

```
text_message = TextMessage.first

text_message.test(12345678910)
```

Comment: Since test is an instance method (a class method would be def self.test) it will hieratically look for the from_number, to_number and message arguments. The to_number is passed as an argument so it will use that. The from_number and message aren't, so eventually it will use the model arguments.

Comment: Awesome - that's easy enough.

Comment: I would recommend not to include external API calls into a model. What if the API returns a 404 or 500? Should the rescue logic also be included into the model? A better approach would be to use a Worker to send those messages or use a Service Object.